# Is this a circular definition in cpython?

Tags: python, cpython

I was reading cpython source code and I am confused about these PyXXXObject, 
[image: screen shot 2017-02-05 at 16 55 52]

I think there is a circular definition

---

it work !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _object {
  struct _typeobject *ob_type; // because it's a pointer!
} PyObject;

typedef struct {
  PyObject ob_base;
} PyVarObject;

#define PyObject_VAR_HEAD PyVarObject ob_base;

typedef struct _typeobject {
  PyObject_VAR_HEAD
  const char *tp_name;
} PyTypeObject;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  PyVarObject var;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure, that’s fine! https://ideone.com/0gnqt7 `ob_type` in `struct _object` there is a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defines are not actually evaluated until they are used so:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
} PyVarObject;
```

Is expanded to:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD 
    Py_ssize_t ob_size; /* Number of items in variable part */
} PyVarObject;
```

And `PyObject_HEAD` is defined as well so the above expands to:

```
typedef struct {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
    Py_ssize_t ob_size; /* Number of items in variable part */
} PyVarObject;
```

and _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA is also a macro which depending on your compile time settings is either nothing or:

```
struct _object *_ob_next;
struct _object *_ob_prev;
```

So the declaration of `PyVarObject` becomes one of:

```
typedef struct {
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
    Py_ssize_t ob_size; /* Number of items in variable part */
} PyVarObject;
```

or:

```
typedef struct {
    struct _object *_ob_next;
    struct _object *_ob_prev;
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
    Py_ssize_t ob_size; /* Number of items in variable part */
} PyVarObject;
```

At this stage the structure definition consists of simple types or pointers to structures that are explicitly stated as `struct` the nice thing about which is that the compiler does not, at this stage, need to know what those structures are, since it knows that these are **pointers** to structures, it just needs to allocate the storage for an address to this structure and remember that the type to be allocated to them is required to match.

This is actually a case of ***forward references*** not *circular dependency*.

*Code examined from CPython source at 2.7.11 version of `Include/object.h` simply because that is what I had to hand.*